# Matlab - plot window arrangement

Tags: matlab, plot, tablelayout, matlab-figure, subplot

Is there a possibility of building a plot window with 8 plot figures disposed in the following manner?

- six of them positioned in a 2 x 3 grid;
- the remaining 2, position in a 1 x 2 grid, underneath the 2 x 3 grid;

I can't use the subplot function, because for the fist 6 I would have `subplot(2, 3, x)` and for the last 2 I would have `subplot(1, 2, x)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last input to the `subplot` command need not be an integer and takes decimal offsets. You can use this to create the plot you want, with the two lowest ones centered under the row above with all figures being the same size as in the following example.

```
figure(1)
subplot(3,3,1)
subplot(3,3,2)
subplot(3,3,3)
subplot(3,3,4)
subplot(3,3,5)
subplot(3,3,6)
subplot(3,3,7.5)
subplot(3,3,8.5)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks yoda, I did not know you can pass fractions to subplot

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
figure
subplot(3,3,1), text(0.5,0.5,'1', 'FontSize',20)
subplot(3,3,2), text(0.5,0.5,'2', 'FontSize',20)
subplot(3,3,3), text(0.5,0.5,'3', 'FontSize',20)
subplot(3,3,4), text(0.5,0.5,'4', 'FontSize',20)
subplot(3,3,5), text(0.5,0.5,'5', 'FontSize',20)
subplot(3,3,6), text(0.5,0.5,'6', 'FontSize',20)
subplot(3,2,5), text(0.5,0.5,'7', 'FontSize',20)
subplot(3,2,6), text(0.5,0.5,'8', 'FontSize',20)
```

[image]